# i am not getting kannada text when i run the perl script on a file

Tags: perl

i am having following code for extracting the text from the html files and writing to a text file. in html it contain kannada text(utf-8) when programs runs i am getting a text file in that i am getting text but its not in proper formate. text is in unreadable formate

```
enter code here
use utf8;
use HTML::FormatText;
my $string = HTML::FormatText->format_file(
'a.html',
leftmargin => 0, rightmargin => 50
);
open mm,">t1.txt";
print mm "$string";
```

so please do help me.how to handle the file formates while we are processing it.

Comment: still i am not able to get kannada text. i am getting this  "à²à²¿à²¤à³à²¤à²¿à²°à²à²à²µà²¨à³à²¨à³
à²à³à²¤à³à²¤à²²à²¾à²°à²¦à³à²à²¦à³" in my out put fil.

Comment: yes its working fine for a single file what should i do to work on multiple files and write the data of all files into a single file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want the output file to be UTF-8 encoded so that the characters from the Kannada language are encoded in the output correctly. Your code is probably trying (and failing) to encode incorrectly into ISO-8859-1 instead.

If so, then what you can do is make sure your file is opened with a UTF-8 encoding filter.

```
use HTML::FormatText;

open my $htmlfh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', 'a.html' or die "cannot open a.html: $!";
my $content = do { local $/; <$htmlfh> }; # read all content from file
close $htmlfh;

my $string = HTML::FormatText->format_string(
    $content,
    leftmargin => 0, rightmargin => 50
);

open my $mm, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', 't1.txt' or die "cannot open t1.txt: $!";
print $mm $string;
```

For further reading, I recommend checking out these docs:

- [perlunitut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunitut.html)
- [perlunifaq](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunifaq.html)
- [perlunicode](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html)

A few other notes:

- The `use utf8` line only makes it so that your Perl script/library may contain UTF formatting. It does not make any changes to how you read or write files.
- Avoid using two-argument forms of `open()` like in your example. It may allow a malicious user to compromise your system in certain cases. (Though, your usage in this example happens to safe.
- When opening a file, you need to add an `or die` afterwards or failures to read or write the file will be silently ignored.

**Update 3/12:** I changed it to read the file in UTF-8 and send that to [HTML::FormatText](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML%3a%3aFormatText). If your `a.html` file is saved with a BOM character at the start, it may have done the right thing anyway, but this should make it always assume UTF-8 for the incoming file.

Comment: still i am not able to get kannada text. i am getting this "à²à²¿à²¤à³à²¤à²¿à²°à²à²à²µà²¨à³à²¨à³ à²à³à²¤à³à²¤à²²à²¾à²°à²¦à³à²à²¦à³" in my out put fil.

Comment: Then, it would appear that HTML::FormatText is not reading your file as UTF-8. I read the documentation linked on CPAN above to find the solution to the rest.

Comment: yes its working fine for a single file what should i do to work on multiple files and write the data of all files into a single file.

Comment: Do it in a loop. Open a new file each time, but only output the destination file once and print each time through the loop. If you need help with Perl basics, you may need to learn Perl. I suggest this site: http://perlmaven.com/perl-tutorial